How to Use Dynamic Schema with React Hook Form
I'm working on a project where I need to implement dynamic schema validation using React Hook Form. Currently, I'm using AJV for this purpose, but I'm encountering performance issues and it's not working as expected. Given my previous positive experiences with Zod, I am considering switching to it for schema validation.
Here's what I need:

Dynamic schema validation on the frontend using React Hook Form.
The same schema validation logic to be reused on the backend.

My current setup:

Frontend: React Native with Expo
Backend: Node.js (Express)

Problems with AJV:

Performance issues on the frontend
Complexity in handling dynamic schemas

Why I prefer Zod:

Simpler API
Better TypeScript support
Easier to handle dynamic schemas

What I'm looking for:

How to integrate Zod with React Hook Form for dynamic schema validation.
Best practices for sharing schema validation logic between the frontend and backend.

If anyone has experience with this setup or can provide examples or best practices, I would greatly appreciate it!
Thanks in advance!

Using AJV with React Hook Form:


Integrated AJV as a custom resolver for React Hook Form.
Created dynamic schemas based on user input and form state.
Validated form data using AJV.


Expected:


Efficient and performant schema validation on the frontend.
Reusability of the same schemas for backend validation.


Issues Faced:


Performance: The validation process slowed down the app, especially with complex or nested schemas.
Complexity: Handling dynamic schemas with AJV was more cumbersome than expected, leading to increased complexity in code maintenance.
Integration with React Hook Form: There were inconsistencies and unexpected behavior when integrating AJV with React Hook Form's validation flow.

